# NGINX configuration to use domain with different ports

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I need to configure my.conf file for nginx, I have a domain, and I want to use two different ports to manage frontend and backend.
The frontend has no problems, I go to dominio.com and it is displayed, while the backend has some problems, I go to dominio.com/api and the 502 is returned, if instead I go to dominio.com:6969/api, my backend returns the correct information, I would like to access my backend just go to domain.com/api without specifying the port, I put the file.conf code below

File.conf

```
server{
    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com;

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:6969;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server{
    if ($host = www.dominio.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = dominio.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com;
    return 404;
}
```

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
port_in_redirect off;
```

I tried putting those definitions in my file but it didn't solve anything, I also tried using ipV6 but nothing.
As mentioned before I expect to be able to access the backend using domain.com/api without specifying the port